# error: ‘FILE’ has no member named ‘__fileL’

Tags: c, linux

I have a version of a program that used to compile to a *.o file, but now it does not, and gives a compiler error.
I have tried to compile my code with gcc compiler on Linux, and the compile fails.

I see compiler error:

```
dspter.c:209:18: error: ‘FILE’ has no member named ‘__fileL’
   lseek ((int)Ofd->__fileL, 1-sizeof(PDAY_REC99), SEEK_END);

dspter.c:220:13: error: ‘FILE’ has no member named ‘__fileL’
   lseek (Ofd->__fileL, 1-sizeof(PDAY_REC99), SEEK_END);
```

```
Read99rec ()
{
    char    bf[20];

    if (curnt.ltype == LOAD_PDAY)
        {
        lseek ((int)Ofd->__fileL, 1-sizeof(PDAY_REC99), SEEK_END);
        fgets (Irec, sizeof(Irec), Ofd);
        memset (bf, NULL, sizeof (bf));
        memcpy (bf, Irec+2, 4);
        count01 += atoi(bf);
        memset (bf, NULL, sizeof (bf));
        memcpy (bf, Irec+6, 6);
        recs += atoi(bf);
        memset (bf, NULL, sizeof (bf));
        memcpy (bf, Irec+12, 16);
        ctrl_tot1 += atof(bf);
        lseek (Ofd->__fileL, 1-sizeof(PDAY_REC99), SEEK_END);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

The `FILE` structure is intended to be an opaque type.  You shouldn't be accessing its members.

You should instead use the `fileno` function which will give you the underlying file descriptor associated with a `FILE` object.

However, in this case you don't want to do that either.  Rather than using `lseek`, use `fseek` which performs the same operation but accepts a `FILE *` instead of a file descriptor number.

Comment: Also, calling `lseek` on the `fileno` of a FILE object can put the FILE out of sync with the kernel-level open file description; those should be `fseek` calls instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advise @zwol
changed to fseek and still see same error, pl review below...

dspter.c: In function ‘Read99rec’:
dspter.c:203:18: error: ‘FILE’ has no member named ‘__fileL’
   fseek ((int)Ofd->__fileL, 1-sizeof(PDAY_REC99), SEEK_END);
                  ^

dspter.c: In function ‘OpenOut’:
dspter.c:186:21: error: ‘FILE’ has no member named ‘__fileL’
  if (fstat((int) Ofd->__fileL, &st) == -1) {
                     ^

Comment: @uday You're still trying to access members of the `FILE` object.  Just pass the `FILE` pointer itself as the first argument.